# HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests no Web scraping no repl

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ao executar o código abaixo, encontro:

> HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests o servidor deve ter limite de tempo
>   entre as requisições.

```
#Imports necessários do bs4  
import bs4  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests  
import time  

#Selecionar o site  
url = 'https://hipsters.jobs/jobs/?l=Brasilia%20-%20Federal%20District%2C%20Brazil&p=1'  
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url),"html.parser")  
time.sleep(3)  
print("\n****************************\n")  


#Quantidade de vagas disponíveis  
quantidade = soup.find("h1", class_='search-results__title col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0').get_text().strip()  
print(quantidade)  
quantidade = quantidade.split()  
quantidade = ''.join(quantidade[0:1])  
quantidade = int(quantidade)  

#quantidade de vagas capturadas  
vagas = 0  
links = []  
for item in soup.select(".listing-item__title"):  
  link = item.a.get('href')  
  links.append(link)  
  vagas += 1  
print(vagas)  

#Verificar se há vagas escondidas e pegá-las  
if quantidade != vagas:  
  for i in range(2,50):  
    url = 'https://hipsters.jobs/jobs/?l=Brasilia%20-%20Federal%20District%2C%20Brazil&p={}'.format(str(i))  
    print(url)  
    time.sleep(10)  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url),"html.parser")  
    for item in soup.select(".listing-item__title"):  
      for l in links:  
        link = item.a.get('href')  
        if link != l:  
          links.append(link)  
          vagas += 1  
          if vagas == quantidade:  
            break  
      break  
    break  

titulos = []  
tags = []  
salarios = []  
datas = []  
empresas = []  
locais = []  
descricoes = []  

for i in links:  
  time.sleep(10)  
  url = 'https://' + i  
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url),"html.parser")  
  titulos.append(soup.select("details-header__title").get_text().strip())  
  tags.append(soup.select("job-type").get_text().strip())
```

Comment: Explica bem o problema e as dificuldades que encontras, tenta filtrar de maneira a colocar o suficiente para reproduzir o problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Bem vindo

Comment: Deu `HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests` o servidor deve ter limite de tempo entre as requisições. Referência [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Comment: Gustavo, o servidor que você está fazendo a raspagem limita a quantidade de requisições que um cliente pode fazer para evitar abuso ou sobrecarga de servidor. Para evitar isso basta você respeitar estas regras e fazer requisições em um intervalo de tempo que o servidor aceite.

Comment: Vá aumentando o tempo em `time.sleep(...)`, tente `time.sleep(10)`, se não der tente `time.sleep(20)`, e assim por diante. Mas no geral isso provavelmente é uma pratica para tentar evitar ataques, coletar dados e/ou evitar lentidão do lado deles, eu vi que eles não tem API, logo não estou certo se o seu código pratica algo que pode ser considerado ilegal, não tenho ideia, o que pode ser um problema (acho)